# Get-PnPProvisioning Template Error - SharePoint 2016

Tags: powershell, sharepoint, sharepoint-2016

I am trying to extract the data using the SharePointPnPPowerShell2016 module.

When I call Get-PnPProvisioningTemplate it start to run, it goes through some of the settings Regional Settings, Supported UI Languages, Audit Settings, Site Security, Fields, Content Types, but then throws an error

Message :Could not load type 'Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.DocumentSet.DocumentSetTemplate' from assembly 'Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.DocumentManagement, Version=16.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=71e9bce111e9429c'.
StackTrace :   at OfficeDevPnP.Core.Framework.Provisioning.ObjectHandlers.ObjectContentType.GetEntities(Web web, PnPMonitoredScope scope, ProvisioningTemplateCreationInformation creationInfo, ProvisioningTemplate template)
   at OfficeDevPnP.Core.Framework.Provisioning.ObjectHandlers.ObjectContentType.ExtractObjects(Web web, ProvisioningTemplate template, ProvisioningTemplateCreationInformation creationInfo)
   at OfficeDevPnP.Core.Framework.Provisioning.ObjectHandlers.SiteToTemplateConversion.GetRemoteTemplate(Web web, ProvisioningTemplateCreationInformation creationInfo)
   at Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.WebExtensions.GetProvisioningTemplate(Web web, ProvisioningTemplateCreationInformation creationInfo)
   at PnPVSExtract_cj.Program.Main(String[] args) in c:\users\a0721713\documents\visual studio 2015\Projects\PnPVSExtract_cj\PnPVSExtract_cj\Program.cs:line 66
Date :11/14/2016 4:56:31 PM

I am running another environment with very similar set up, and it progress to List Instances and runs without problems.

Any ideas would help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have seen that error when a outdated version of the CSOM assemblies had been installed;
try installing the latest version of the [SharePoint Server 2016 Client Components SDK](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=51679)